It doesn't let me resize partition. How can I claim the free space?
I managed to be in a frustrating situation in which I had to delete my previous OS and then I cannot claim all of the unused free space, like in the image:

So I want the /home partition to claim all of the "sin asignar" space, problem is that it doesn't let me, not even booting from a live USB. How can I do it? The image is from my operating system, but I have trying using a lve USB.

Well, you can't resize it to cover the free space – obviously! There's your "/boot" partition in between.
So, you'll need to make a new partition and simply copy over the contents of the old. (then you could delete the old)
However, this looks dangerously much like a legacy msdos/MBR partitioning, with the Grub boot loader written to the disk directly? But then you also have an EFI boot partition. That's a bit strange and points to an older system with quirks in its firmware implementation.
So, first things first: Since this seems to be an MBR-partitioned system, you cannot make a new partition. Check that: can you make a new partition in the unassigned space?

(good case) If you can, you have a modern partition table (GPT), do that, format with btrfs, and use btrfs device add to add the newly created to your existing btrfs pool. That's it. Btrfs can combine the space on multiple partitions to store your data.
(bad case) If not ("cannot create more than 4 primary partition"): the system was set up in a very backwards way. You'll need to do the following. All of this has to be done from an external boot stick.


Backup your 28 GB of data (contents of /,/home and /boot) to a separate drive. No excuses. You need a backup, anyways, and this is the perfect time to have one.
you can Move the partition containing /boot (sda4) to the beginning of the free space. (select partition, "resize/move", change "Free Space Preceeding" to 0)

after doing that, check that your system still boots. Else, repair the boot loader


now, do the same to your sda5, so that the free space is after it.

again, make sure things still boot


now, you can extend the size of your sda5 to the right
afterwards, make sure things still boot, if this is an SSD, run sudo fstrim -a

Next time you set up a system, make sure you're not using MSDOS partition tables anymore (but that's not even an option anymore, on any installer I've seen).

Frankly, if you're in bad case, then I'd do the backup, boot to an installer medium, use that to erase all partitions and create a GPT partition table, and do a clean-slate installation, and copy over what I have in /home from my backup to my new system. Would be faster for me.

I managed to create a new partiyion in the unassigned space: https://imgur.com/a/partitions-VJeFMxY?third_party=1

sadly, you didn't follow my guide to format it as btrfs, so do that now, then add the device to the existing btrfs pool

Mülller, so I ran 'sudo mkfs.btrfs -L gfg /dev/sda3 -f', to change the filesystem to btrfs and then 'btrfs device add /dev/sda3', but what other device should I add?

you do that adding to the existing sda5 pool, so that the available space in that simply grows by the size of sda3.

So I ended up with this. Is this what you were talking about: https://imgur.com/a/new-partition-status-ZVCIqGW

looks good to me!

Thank you very much!
